# Python: Insert a dynamic value along with static value?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert a one dynamic value along with static value in MySQL database using python. When I execute the query with dynamic value alone is working, check the below query.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rfid(tagname) VALUES (%s)", (txt))
```

But How to execute a dynamic value along with static value? I tried below, its not working.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rfid(tagname,weight) VALUES (%s,%d)", (txt,30))
error:
execute
query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Actually I gave 30, it is a number.

Python version v2.7 and MySQL version is 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already hard-coding 30, why not just hard code it in the `insert` statement?

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rfid(tagname, weight) VALUES (%s, 30)", (txt))
```

Comment: thank you, it works but does it help in SQL injection ?? I mean dont we have 
query like 

       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rfid(tagname, weight) VALUES (?, 30)", (txt))

Comment: @hemantsingh yes - note this isn't just string replacement - it's the cursor's method to bind variables. As long as you aren't manipulating the first parameter  (i.e., the statement) with user input, this should be safe against SQL injection.